# Adding place's review in a viewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-places-api, swift4

I would like to add in a my viewController the reviews of a place (i'm working with google places API), something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjAYa.jpg)

and following the google places documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), i created a viewController with only a label inside and this code (for now i am trying to show only the text and the author name) but is not working (moreover, I do not know if a label is good for doing this kind of thing), what is wrong, how can i adjust it?

// UPDATE

//ViewController

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import GooglePlaces
import Alamofire

private let RIdentifier = "myReviewTableCell"


class ReviewClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var RtableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myReview: UILabel!

    var places:[QPlace] = []
    var index2:Int = -1






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard index2 >= 0, places.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        let place = places[index2]

        myReview.text = place.name

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // TABLE VIEW





    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        print("numberOfsection Call")
        return 1
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return 1
    }




    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! myReviewTableCell

        let place = places[index2]

        cell.revSelect(place: place)

       return (cell)
    }

 }
```

// Custom TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

private let json = """
{
"reviews" : [
{
"author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
"author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
"language" : "en",
"profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
"rating" : 5,
"relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
"text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
"time" : 1491144016
}
]
}
"""

class myReviewTableCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var revText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var revRating: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var revAuthor: UILabel!

     var place: QPlace?




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }




    func revSelect(place:QPlace) {



        NearbyPlaces.getPlaceDetails(place: place) { (place) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let review = place.details?[json] as? [String:Any] {
                    do {
                        if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let decoded = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
                            print(decoded.reviews)
                 // revText ??
                 // revAuthor ??
                        } else {
                            print("data is not available")
                        }
                    } catch (let e) {
                        print(e)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {

    struct Review: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {

        let text: String
        let authorName: String

        var description: String {
            return "Review text: \(text) authorName: \(authorName)"
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case text
            case authorName = "author_name"
        }
    }

    let reviews: [Review]
}
```

Comment: For a list of content, like reviews. you should look at using a UITableView or a UICollectionView

Comment: you're right, but my principale problem is the function  func revSelect(place:QPlace) , how i have to adjust it to show the reviews?

Comment: when the response comes back and you get a bunch of reviews returned. set those as the data source for the tableVIew

Comment: can give me a little example, is the first time to me to trying doing something like this

Comment: there is not much point in providing some example code that you will not understand and will not work for your project. try working through these examples: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html and https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/ which will help you understand how to use a table view

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, i update the answer can you give a look? I understand what i have to do but i still don't know in my revSelect func (in tableViewCell class) how can i make for example "revAuthor.text = "author_url"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown above has a number of things wrong with it that would be causing you some issues. Here are some notes/tips to help you.

1. You need to set the tableView delegate and datasource (usually to self)
2. Your data for the tableView should be an array of reviews for the current place like `var reviews = [Review]()`
3. You do not need `let place = places[index2]` or `myReview.text = place.name`
4. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` func should return `self.reviews.count`
5. Your tableViewCell should not be making API requests to fetch it's data.
6. Make your API request in the view controller. parse the response and then set self.reviews = your result data from API.
7. Your cellForRowAt func should dequeue a cell, get the review information from the reviews array and assign the data to the cell.

Example cellForRow at

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! myReviewTableCell

    let review = reviews[indexPath.row]
    cell.authorNameLabel.text = review.authorName
    return cell
}
```

When you load this view controller you should pass/set the place (you can segue to this view controller and then set the place in prepareForSegue) and then once you have this make a request to the API and fetch all reviews for this place. That is the data for the tableView.

If I was doing this, my approach would look something like this..

```
class ReviewsTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var place: Place?
    var reviews = [Review]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let place = self.place else { return }

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // not exact syntax, doing this from memory
        Alamofire.request(urlForApiRequest).responseJSON {
           // parse the json response to get review models using JSONDecoder()
           self.reviews = reviews
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Then just to clarify, I would have extensions below for each of the delegates

```
extension ReviewsTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   // table view functions in here
}
```